# How to check whether each value of one column maps to exactly one value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('bbcddee'), 'B': list('klmnnoi')})

   A  B
0  b  k
1  b  l
2  c  m
3  d  n
4  d  n
5  e  o
6  e  i
```

and I would like to create a dictionary from the columns `A` and `B` using e.g.

```
dict(zip(df.A, df.B))
```

Before doing this, I would like to check whether each value in `A` is mapped to only one value in `B`; if not, an error should be thrown; above that is not the case as `b` is mapped to `k` and `l` and `e` is mapped to `o` and `i`.

One way of approaching it would be:

```
df[df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].transform(lambda x: len(set(x))) > 1]
```

which returns

```
   A  B
0  b  k
1  b  l
5  e  o
6  e  i
```

However, that requires a `lambda` which might make it slow. Does anyone see an option to speed it up?

Comment: with the above you'll only have two items in your dict, are you sure that's the output you want?

Comment: @Datanovice: That's just a check. In case I assign the results back to e.g. `df1`, I could then do `if not df1.empty: throw error`. So I don't use this output to generate my `dict` but just as a consistency check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `groupby` with `nunique` to get how many unique values in 'B' belong to each unique value in 'A'.

```
df.groupby('A').B.nunique()
#A
#b    2
#c    1
#d    1
#e    2
#Name: B, dtype: int64
```

And so you can check if any of them have more than 1 mapping:

```
df.groupby('A').B.nunique().gt(1).any()
#True
```

---

The above is conceptually no different from what you proposed. However, there is often a major performance gain if you are able to use a built-in groupby operation, which has been "optimized", as opposed to a slow lambda that requires a loop. We can see that as the DataFrame gets large the lambda can become nearly 100x slower, which is a big deal when things are starting to take seconds to compute.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def gb_lambda(df):
    return df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x))).gt(1)

def gb_nunique(df):
    return df.groupby('A').B.nunique().gt(1)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, n//2, n), 
                                  'B': np.random.randint(0, n//2, n)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: gb_lambda(df),
        lambda df: gb_nunique(df),
    ],
    labels=['groupby with lambda', 'Groupby.nunique'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2,18)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel='~len(df)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine as well (upvoted). To get the dataframe with all duplicates one could then do `df[df.groupby('A').B.transform('nunique') > 1]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pd.Series.duplicated` and `df.duplicated` with `keep` parameter set to `False`

```
df[df.A.duplicated(keep=False) & (~df.duplicated(keep=False))]

   A  B
0  b  k
1  b  l
5  e  o
6  e  i
```

---

#### Details

```
df.A.duplicated(keep=False) # To eliminate `A` values occur only once

0     True
1     True
2    False # ----> `c` which has no duplicates 
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

~df.duplicated(keep=False) # Capture values having different mapping
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False # ----> d n
4    False # ----> d n
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: That's a nice one (upvoted; I wait with acceptance whether something else shows up).

Comment: Thanks @Cleb Sure, much better answer might pop up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `filter`

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x : x['B'].nunique()>1)
   A  B
0  b  k
1  b  l
5  e  o
6  e  i
```

Comment: Works fine too 9upvoted), but then we have `filter` in combination with `lambda`, so not sure how much better that would be compared to what I have; would have to do some timings :)